# How do I convert a PLY model into a list of triangles?

Tags: graphics, 3d, mesh, point-clouds, triangle

I've wanted to try rendering the [Stanford Bunny model](https://sites.cc.gatech.edu/projects/large_models/bunny.html) in my own simple raytracer. When I download and unzip the model, I get two directories of `.ply` files called `data/` and `reconstruction/`, respectively. I believe the model is 100% composed of triangles (so it is a triangle mesh).

Right now, I just want a way to convert all those `.ply` files into a list of triangles (triplets of vertices). How do I do this?